# Consuming SOAP service with WS-Security and wss4j and Spring - Request scoped Wss4jSecurityInterceptor?

Tags: java, soap, spring-boot, ws-security, wss4j

I'm trying to customize a soap client library that uses Spring and Wss4j2. It uses basic username/password token for logging in. Here's my problem, my application needs to access the SOAP webservice with different username and passwords per request, depending on who's accessing my application. So I can't just configure the Wss4jSecurityInterceptor with a single username and password, I need to set it for each request. I can't figure out how to do this since Wss4jSecurityInterceptor isn't very extensible. It seems to use an instance of Wss4jHandler that's instantiated in the declaration of the class field making it not overridable. It seems to be this class that handles the password piece.

Any suggestions aside from just making my own copies of these classes and changing what I need in them?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I thought about the same problem yesterday.

Comment: My "solution" was to made a copy of the class in my code base and modify it as needed as I mentioned in my question. Better approach might have been to create a modification to the class in the Spring project and propose it as a more flexible option. But time constraints and all. It's hopefully temporary since we plan to not be using the SOAP api forever